# How to prevent jquery funcions overriding

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
<script src="<c:url value="/ruleengineui/resources/js/vendor/jquery.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/ruleengineui/resources/js/Dummyjs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>"></script>
```

I am importing above two files to my jsp file. But the second file will override the first one.How can I solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: why does these two js file with same functionality exist?

Comment: <script src="<c:url value="/ruleengineui/resources/js/vendor/jquery.js" />"></script>      This file support jquery modal       <script src="<c:url value="/ruleengineui/resources/js/Dummyjs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>"></script>       This file support Jqgrid... I want to use both together..

Comment: @ArunJose maybe you can take just one file that support both. jquery-version.min.js is just a minimized version of jquery.js.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/9ezy09ep/54/, and use the External Resources in that page.

```
$(selector).dialog();
$(selector).jqGrid({});
```

Comment: just reference jquery.min.js, jquery ui js, jquery.jqGrid.min.js and the corresponding css file, it depends on what u need.